# [WARN]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS Interface

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to run the husky_gazebo node.. But for some reason, I'm not able to control husky using the teleop_keyboard.

The status once I run roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch is:

```
... logging to /home/aditya/.ros/log/956de5ca-06c6-11e7-ac58-c8ff287985b5/roslaunch-aditya-Lenovo-Yoga710-14ISK-13541.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
deprecated: xacro tags should be prepended with 'xacro' xml namespace.
Use the following script to fix incorrect usage:
find . -iname "*.xacro" | xargs sed -i 's#<([/]?)(if|unless|include|arg|property|macro|insert_block)#<\1xacro:\2#g'
when processing file: /home/aditya/CSE180/src/husky_gazebo/urdf/description.gazebo.xacro

xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://aditya-Lenovo-Yoga710-14ISK:37005/

SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

/ekf_localization/base_link_frame: base_link
/ekf_localization/frequency: 50
/ekf_localization/imu0: imu/data
/ekf_localization/imu0_config: [False, False, Fa...
/ekf_localization/imu0_differential: True
/ekf_localization/imu0_queue_size: 10
/ekf_localization/imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: True
/ekf_localization/odom0: husky_velocity_co...
/ekf_localization/odom0_config: [False, False, Fa...
/ekf_localization/odom0_differential: False
/ekf_localization/odom0_queue_size: 10
/ekf_localization/odom_frame: odom
/ekf_localization/two_d_mode: True
/ekf_localization/world_frame: odom
/husky_joint_publisher/publish_rate: 50
/husky_joint_publisher/type: joint_state_contr...
/husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
/husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
/husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 6.0
/husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 2.0
/husky_velocity_controller/base_frame_id: base_link
/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
/husky_velocity_controller/enable_odom_tf: False
/husky_velocity_controller/estimate_velocity_from_position: False
/husky_velocity_controller/left_wheel: ['front_left_whee...
/husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
/husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
/husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 3.0
/husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 1.0
/husky_velocity_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
/husky_velocity_controller/publish_rate: 50
/husky_velocity_controller/right_wheel: ['front_right_whe...
/husky_velocity_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
/husky_velocity_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
/husky_velocity_controller/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
/husky_velocity_controller/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.875
/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
/rosdistro: kinetic
/rosversion: 1.12.6
/twist_mux/locks: [{'topic': 'e_sto...
/twist_mux/topics: [{'topic': 'joy_t...
/use_sim_time: True
NODES
/
base_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
ekf_localization (robot_localization/ekf_localization_node)
gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
spawn_husky_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
twist_marker_server (interactive_marker_twist_server/marker_server)
twist_mux (twist_mux/twist_mux)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [13562]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [13567]
process[robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [13572]
process[base_controller_spawner-4]: started with pid [13573]
process[ekf_localization-5]: started with pid [13580]
process[twist_marker_server-6]: started with pid [13593]
process[twist_mux-7]: started with pid [13599]
process[spawn_husky_model-8]: started with pid [13625]
[ INFO] [1489285026.759704645]: [twist_marker_server] Initialized.
[ INFO] [1489285026.963734797]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1489285026.964849792]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1489285027.836769729, 1298.500000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1489285027.885431704, 1298.550000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1232] multiple inconsistent exists due to fixed joint reduction overwriting previous value [true] with [false].
[ INFO] [1489285028.861646869, 1298.680000000]: Laser Plugin (robotNamespace = /), Info: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1489285028.861787644, 1298.680000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)!
[ INFO] [1489285028.863121697, 1298.680000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /) <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[spawn_husky_model-8] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/aditya/.ros/log/956de5ca-06c6-11e7-ac58-c8ff287985b5/spawn_husky_model-8*.log
[WARN] [1489285057.209350, 1326.810000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[base_controller_spawner-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/aditya/.ros/log/956de5ca-06c6-11e7-ac58-c8ff287985b5/base_controller_spawner-4*.log
```

I have tried the answers here: #q214712.

But sadly in vain. I have managed to run it on other machines. But it refuses to run on mine.

ros debugger (roswtf) returns the following:

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context

Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings

Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 3 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

/robot_state_publisher:
/joint_states
/twist_marker_server:
/twist_marker_server/feedback
/rqt_gui_py_node_13212:
/statistics
/ekf_localization:
/husky_velocity_controller/odom
/imu/data
/set_pose
/twist_mux:
/e_stop
/cmd_vel
/platform_control/cmd_vel
/joy_teleop/cmd_vel
/gazebo:
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gazebo/set_link_state
WARNING These nodes have died:

spawn_husky_model-8
base_controller_spawner-4
WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:

receiving transform from [/slam_gmapping] that differed from ROS time by 1489300903.76s
running rostopic echo husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel gives me:
rostopic echo /husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

FOr which I have tried the solution given in the link below: #q12083.

I have `controller_manager` installed. But it doesn't seem to load when I launch gazebo.

Kindly let me know what the issue could be !
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256820/%5Bwarn%5D:-controller-spawner-couldn%27t-find-the-expected-controller_manager-ros-interface/) by [jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29179/jarvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I solved the problem ! The package that needed to be downloaded was

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control

Then of course, I had to include gazebo with robot name space header in the xml file which was given in the following link:

http://answers.ros.org/question/214712/gazebo-controller-spawner-warning/

Thanks @ufr3c_tjc appreciate the help!

---

Originally posted by [jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29179/jarvis/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ansonwu](https://answers.ros.org/users/60427/ansonwu/) on 2020-10-03**:
Thanks, that works in my project, merci!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your computer is slow, sometimes Gazebo doesn't launch controller manager fast enough for the controller_spawner service. This happens on my machine the first launch each day. But I doubt this is the issue if gazebo is loading within 30 seconds. Try putting the controller_spawner launch lines in a separate file and launch it once the rest of gazebo is up and running for a little bit just to be sure it has time to launch controller_manager.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29179/jarvis/) on 2017-03-18**:
I didn't work. The gazebo launches in 30 seconds. In fact it loads in 5 seconds. But the controller_manager doesn't load after 30 seconds. I have an SSD+Core i5 with 16 gb RAM so I don't think its slow. I even downloaded the controller_manager from github:source into my workspace. Still doesn't work

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-03-20**:
Did you install ros_control from debian packages? ie `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control`? Are you running this as a Gazebo simulation, or on the actual robot? If it's gazebo, you need to launch the ros_control gazebo plugin which serves as controller_manager interface when using Gazebo

**Comment by [jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29179/jarvis/) on 2017-03-20**:
I have installed the mentioned package. The controller_manager is added in the launch file. The launch works on my lab PC. But it does not work on my laptop. And my laptop is faster than my lab PC (in my lab PC I run it on a virtual machine.). And I am running it as a simulation.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-03-20**:
You should have the gazebo_ros_control plugin running when you launch. This sits in the URDF and is used by gazebo as the controller manager interface. See [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control). This is where gazebo handles the ros_control side of things, not the through normal cm.

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2017-03-29**:
@jarvis hey, did you figure out what was wrong?

**Comment by [jarvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29179/jarvis/) on 2017-03-29**:
Not yet. The problem still persists.

**Comment by [utsavrai](https://answers.ros.org/users/60696/utsavrai/) on 2020-10-09**:
thanks @ufr3c_tjc for your insight on this problem. I was running roscore on cloud system and gazebo on ros slave and the controller spawner launch was getting timeout. I separated the controller launch which resolved the controller spawner error but now I am getting p gain errors

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-06-02**:
"launch it once the rest of gazebo is up and running for a little bit just to be sure it has time to launch controller_manager"
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found that if you're using kinetic all of the following packages are required (even if you installed ros-desktop-full)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-control ros-kinetic-joint-state-controller ros-kinetic-effort-controllers ros-kinetic-position-controllers ros-kinetic-velocity-controllers ros-kinetic-ros-controllers ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-control
```

Hopefully this helps someone else

---

Originally posted by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) with karma: 165 on 2020-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2